# Different execution from DNX and .NET CLI

Tags: .net, architecture, publish, dnx, .net-core

On DNX when we publish one app using `dnu publish` we get for each command defined in `project.json` a script which to execute the required action uses `dnx.exe`. The important point here is that the execution of the app itself is made by `dnx`.

On my understanding DNX is the interface between the virtual machine (CLR or CoreCLR) and the OS. In that case calling DNX would boot the chosen virtual machine, take care of dependencies and start the app there.

With the new .NET CLI things are different. When we publish the app with `dotnet publish` we get, apart from other things, the files *projectname.dll*, *projectname.pdb* and one native executable *projectname*.

The execution here is done directly through the app. There is no software which intermediates the process. We run the native executable and in my understanding it boots the CLR, interfaces with the OS and runs the app.

The main difference is that with DNX with had one unique piece of software installed in the OS which executed the apps. With .NET CLI for each app we have one native executable that seems to do the job of DNX.

It seems there has been a huge shift from one approach to the other. My question here is: what is the motivation for this huge shift? Why abbandon the first approach and go to the second one for app execution?

Comment: It is advertised as a simpler way to do things, without having the wrangle dnvm/dnu/dnx.  You don't have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the downsides of dnx was that dnx poisoned your app with its dependecies. With dnx there was a native bootstrapper that bootstrapped the Clr/CoreClr and then some managed code that ran before the actual application was executed. This managed code required dependencies. If the application happened to use the same dependencies (possibly different versions) it would not use the version that the application referenced but the version dnx referenced. So, dnx effectively pinned dependencies (have you ever noticed cases where `dnu build` would fail but `dnx run` would work fine - this was because the dependency that caused build failure was brought by dnx). Interestingly, this was one of the reasons why dnx stopped using JSon.NET internally and had own JSon parser (the epic 'we no longer support comments in project.json' thread on github) - to not pin the version of JSon.Net.

In dotnet there is no managed code between the bootstrapper and your code. Your .exe is just a renamed bootstrapper (corerun.exe) which bootstrapps the runtime and invokes your app. dotnet cli is actually just a set of tools and the runtime is a set of packages your application depends on (if you are using CoreClr). Yes, there is no more compilation at runtime (`dotnet run` first compiles the app to .exe and then runs it). I think a shared runtime is a possibility in the future.